# STM32 - update firmware from data stored in SRAM

Tags: stm32, sram, ota, stm32cubeide

I would like to remotely update the firmware of my STM32WLE5 device. I can transfer the new binary file from the server to the STM's SRAM using my custom link only, which means I cannot utilize other native update procedures provided by STM, such as UART. However, I'm unsure about what steps to take with the data once it's in the SRAM.

Does anyone know how to update the firmware using the data stored in the SRAM?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Google: "How to write a bootloader".